# Address Alignment for Union

Tags: assembly, memory-alignment

I am a bit confused about Memory address alingment for union.

```
typedef union { 
               char state[x];
               char encode[4];
               int index;
} Location;
```

We use several alignment rule while writing code, ex:

```
int      4 bit alignment
double   4 bit for linux
char *   4 bit for linux
```

"how that union will be aligned" 
For those conditions;
If

```
   x < 4      ?
   x = 4      ?
   x > 4      ?
```

platform linux 
assembly x86 64 bit

NOTE: If you have better opinion, feel free when improve that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what your actual question is :-)

But, if you're asking how that union will be aligned, a union has to follow two relevant rules here.

1. All items must start at the start of the union.
2. The union as a whole must have the alignment of its strictest component.

In other words, it's likely that the `int` is the driving force here in terms of alignment

The value of `x` is irrelevant here if the alignment of a single `char` is one. It's not the whole *array* that needs to be aligned, just each element of it.

Comment: @fatai: I'm no longer confused but my answer is the same. `x` has no bearing on the alignment since it's not _arrays_ that need to be aligned, just individual elements. A 64-bit int is going to have more stringent alignment requirements that a 8-bit `char` (or even an array of a billion 8-bit `char` elements).